# Vim command mode percent expansion

Tags: vim, text-editors

My typical day-to-day workflow in Vim involves having two vertical panes; production code on the left, and the tests on the right.

I frequently switch languages (and test frameworks), so I like to create a new mapping for running my test code each session. Let’s say I’m doing some Ruby project and I’m driving out a class in `lib/importer.rb`. The accompanying specs live in `spec/lib/importer_spec.rb`.

To create my mapping for running the specs, I would focus on the pane showing the specs, and enter the following:

```
:nnoremap -g :!rspec %<cr>
```

*Note: I use hyphen/minus as my leader key.*

This works, but only if the spec pane has focus when I hit <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>. If the production pane has focus and I hit the mapping, *rspec* will try and run the production code, which doesn’t make sense.

To work around this, I can write the absolute path to the spec file:

```
:nnoremap -g :!rspec spec/lib/importer_spec.rb<cr>
```

This works, though it is a bit cumbersome to write.

While reading [*Practical Vim*](http://pragprog.com/book/dnvim/practical-vim) last night, I realised that in command mode you can use `%` expansion — you write `%` and then hit <kbd>tab</kbd>, and the percent is replaced with the absolute path to the file in the currently focused pane.

If I do this:

```
:!rspec %
```

…And then hit <kbd>tab</kbd>, I get this:

```
:!rspec spec/lib/importer_spec.rb
```

And that’s great! However, If I do this:

```
:nnoremap -g :!rspec %
```

…And then hit <kbd>tab</kbd>, I get this:

```
:nnoremap -g :!rspec %^I
```

I am a good person and I pay my taxes. Why is this happening to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command completion by default isn't recognized in mappings (and recorded in macros). You can define an alternative key in the obscure `'wildcharm'` option and use that. However, insertion of the current filename can be done in an easier and more straightforward way. Instead of completing `%`, just insert an equivalent Vimscript expression via `<C-r>`:

```
:nnoremap -g :!rspec <C-r>=expand('%')<cr><cr>
```

PS: To properly deal with *all* sorts of filenames, additionally use `shellescape()`:

```
:nnoremap -g :!rspec <C-r>=shellescape(expand('%'), 1)<cr><cr>
```

PPS: I hope you're not actually manually typing in the mapping every time, but use a *filetype plugin* or `:autocmd` to define this automatically for the test buffers. I'd definitely recommend to automate it in that way.